# c# - StartsWith, EndsWith and between them

Tags: c#

```
string qwe = "ABCD";

if(qwe.StartsWith("A") && qwe.EndsWith("D"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message");
}
```

What I need is to make also a decision for B and C but not StartsWith and EndsWith, it's really hard for me to explain but just like this:

```
if(qwe.Second("B"))
{
    //Do anything
}

and

if(qwe.Third("C"))
{
    //Do anything
}
```

Comment: check out C#'s string functions, and also regular expressions. Either one could probably help you. Or treat the string as an array. Lots to search for, which you could probably have done already, to be honest.

Comment: stringa are array of chars. You can look at the second char of the string using _qwe[1] == 'B'_

Comment: Is your qwe variable at a fixed length?

Comment: yes, fixed length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that you can [access characters via index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx)(zero based)?

```
if(qwe.Length >= 2 && qwe[1] == 'B')
{
    //Do anything
}

if(qwe.Length >= 3 && qwe[2] == 'C')
{
    //Do anything
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the answer I'm looking for..
I dont have enough reputation to +1 your answer

Comment: @JakeZynderFord: well, you can accept the answer if you want